# How to add custom annotations based on labels with alertmanager templates?

Tags: go-templates, prometheus-alertmanager

I have an Alertmanager, sending alerts to an Alerta.

Alerts sent contains annotations field with only description, and a tons of labels.

What I would like to do is create a template for Alertmanager and add another annotation based on my labels

I have this template

```
default.tmpl: |
    Annotations:
    foo = {{ .labels.foo.Value }}
```

My alerts are send like this

```
{ 
    "status": "firing",
       "labels": {
           "foo": "bar"
    },
    "annotations": {
        "description": "some description"
    }, 
}
```

And I would like to send them like this

```
{ 
    "status": "firing",
       "labels": {
           "foo": "bar"
    },
    "annotations": {
        "description": "some description",
        "foo": "bar"
    }, 
}
```